# How do I embed a stream in a video player?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video-streaming, webrtc

I am using a simple functional component for react.js. Inside this component I have a video player that can standard format videos from my local computer or external url.

For example

```
<video
   className="player__video viewer"
   src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4"
   type="video/mp4"
/>
```

In this case, the player reads the external url address and plays the mp4 video

But at this point I have 2 problems:
Firstly, I have found several solutions that are likely to work, but they do not work.
Secondly, I can’t find and don’t know where to look for links to streaming video broadcasts, so that I could test the solutions

If now in my player I just change the link to the streaming address, should this work?

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful if you give us some information about the streaming type. I think it depends on which streaming service you want to use.

Comment: @DerKarim, If I'm not mistaken, my project uses a node.js server to transfer webRTC video with using socket-io